# Two IP on the same subnetwork

Tags: ip, route, kubuntu

My problem is the following. (kubuntu 14.04 64bits, kernel 4.40)

I have a remote computer (on another place, I can't go on site) that have two network cards.

On the second card (`eth1`), I have a dhcp client which serve the IP `192.168.0.189/24`. Through this IP, I can connect with Teamviewer or anydesk.

On the first card (`eth0`), the IP is set to `192.168.2.10/24`. All works well.

But I have a device IP that IP is `192.168.0.100/24` and *must* be connected on `eth0` (note that `192.168.0.100/24` is free on `eth1`).

So I add the IP `192.168.0.110/24` to `eth0` to access this new device.

The problem is, in that case, we cannot initiate new connection on Teamviewer or anydesk.

So, I'm looking to explain my system that it must use

- `eth0` to access `192.168.0.100`
- `eth1` to all other `192.168.0.x`

I think that `route` could be what I want, but I don't want to test it right now, because on error, things will be terrible to debug.

My question is:

Will the command `route add 192.168.0.100/24 eth0` be enough?

Should I generate some script for the other `192.168.0.x` addresses?

---

```
#ip a before ip addr add 192.168.0.110/24 dev eth0
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.10/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.189/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft 401100sec preferred_lft forever


#ip a after ip addr add 192.168.0.110/24 dev eth0
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.10/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.110/24 scope global secondary enp0s8
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    

2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.189/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft 401100sec preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

ip route add /32 via  dev

So I think if you did something like:

`ip route add 192.168.0.100/32 via 192.168.0.189 dev eth0`

I think that would work no?

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

- a free /32 address on the interface (I assume 192.168.0.111)
- a /32 route

```
# delete the old address if necessary
# ip addr del 192.168.0.110/24 dev eth0
ip addr add 192.168.0.111/32 dev eth0

ip route add 192.168.0.110/32 dev eth0
```